# Alternate days in datepicker

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to `addClass` in alternate Saturdays. I have tried 2 methods but none works properly.

**#1**
I added `:odd` to every every `tr`. **[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/jajoevjy/1/)**

```
$('.ui-datepicker-calendar tr:odd').each(function(){
   $(this).addClass('odd');
});
```

But If see moth of April ending and starting May are not in odd state.

**#2**
I got an even odd hack somewhere in fiddle. **[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/jajoevjy/3/)**

```
$('td.ui-datepicker-week-end .ui-state-default').each(function(i, el) {
   if (i % 2 === 0) { 
    $(this).addClass('sat');
   }
   else { 
    $(this).addClass('sun');                
   }
});

$('.sat').each(function(i, el) {
   if (i % 2 === 0) { 
    $(this).addClass('work-sat');
   }
   else {
    $(this).addClass('non-sat');    
   }
});
```

This works fine but if you change some next previous month with next, prev buttons. it does automatically even becomes odd and vice-versa. Also Auto change after some months it changes automatically.
I don't know why does it happens?

Answer (score 2):

The safest way to do this is to read the year month and date from the table cells, and then check the day

```
$('.ui-datepicker td .ui-state-default').each(function(i, el) {
    var month = $(el).parent().attr('data-month');
    var year = $(el).parent().attr('data-year');
    var day = $(el).text();
    var date = new Date(year, month, day);

    if (date.getDay() == 6) {

      i += 1;
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        $(el).addClass('work-sat');
      } else {
        $(el).addClass('non-sat');
      }
    }
});
```

If i marked the alternate saturdays just make i = 0; at the init and when onChangeMonthYear function is called.

You can also set the timeout to 1 so that the marking appears to be done instantly.

here is the full fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jajoevjy/8/

Comment: Hi Liviu, Thank for your answer. `$(el).parent().attr('data-month')` data-attributes for month and year is not visible on local same code and the same version has been implemented. But in fiddle data-attr is visible. Do you know why?

Comment: You don't have it on the element at all if you inspect it, or do you not get the value using jquery?

Comment: I got the reason. I'm using `beforeShowDay` and this is disabling. I have to use `beforeShowDay` because I have specified some other random dates.